# How to protect table cells in Google Sheets from myself (accidental edits)?

Tags: google-sheets

As in Microsoft Excel, I want to protect certain cells in Google Sheets. This is possible, but asides from the fact that it is quite confusing to me, it doesn't seem possible to protect cells from myself? The write-protection isn't extended to my edits, if I am the author of the spreadsheet. I need to stay in control of it otherwise, but I don't want to sacrifice write protection for this "privilege".

Did I miss something?

Do you have any recommendation of how to work around this?

Comment: You can rely on the revision history to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

On the protection settings choose

> To show a warning when anyone makes an edit

Reference:

- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en)